# Clipping multiparted shapefiles to multiparted shapefiles?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, clip, arcgis-10.4, splitting

Using ArcGIS Desktop 10.4. I am trying to clip a multiparted (polygon) layer to a multiparted polygon layer.  Specifically, I have a statewide dataset consisting of multiple irregular polygons confined to the entire state boundary;  I want to clip those features to the individual state counties, which I have in both a complete shapefile consisting of constituent county shapes as well as individual, separate county shapes.  I don't want to have to run a clip on each of our 100 counties, so I figured there'd be a way of using the complete statewide county layer.

Can this be done or am I doomed to batch clipping?

Comment: What is wrong with clip tool output?

Comment: NC has 100 counties- too much work to click through a batch clip. The Split tool did the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you need the [Split](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/split.htm) tool. If you don't have an advanced license, you can write a script to loop through your counties layer, selecting each county one at a time, and performing the clip then.